# Как изменить Hello, как показано на картинке!

Tags: java

[image: Задача]

Подскажите пжл, как сделать то???

Comment: Обычным `System.out.print`...

Comment: Подсказка: печатать можно не только текст, но и звездочки.

Comment: Здесь не приветствуются просьбы выполнить за вас ваше задание. Пытайтесь сами, а если возникнут проблемы -- задавайте конкретный вопрос, и напишите, что вы пытались сделать и что не конкретно не получается. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Хммм..спасибо подсказку и очередной ответ!))

Comment: Хмм.. а есть исходный код, который нужно отредактировать? (тот самый класс HelloWorld с картинки) 
Если укажешь его, тебе с бОльшей вероятностью помогут)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь не выполняют задачки/домашние задания за других, а помогают людям с трудностями возникающими *во время* решения.
(Здесь написано как нужно задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.)

В вашем же случае могу лишь дать 2 подсказки:

1. `System.out.print(), System.out.println()`
2. Цикл for()

Желаю удачи вам в изучении, и в дальнейшем постарайтесь формулировать вопросы более грамотно)